# Anaconda don't install navigator

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed anaconda on windows10. Anaconda prompt emerge in menu, but other programs like navigator, spider, jupiter weren't installed (I can't find their .exe on laptop). And prompt doesn't work correctly. log("C:\Users\Vl\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" isn't internal or external comand).

Comment: If I understand your question, click on the start button and locate Anaconda3 in the list. Expand this and should notice Anaconda Navigator and click to execute it. OR search for Anaconda Navigator after clicking start.You should see all the missing programs within Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using command line (**using anaconda prompt**):

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

or

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```